# Placeholder for Signer Details in docusign via stimulsoft

Tags: java, docusignapi, stimulsoft

**Summary:**
I am using Stimulsoft report viewer/designer for generating reports and sending reports to DocuSign for digital signature.
While sending the reports to DocuSign, the signature placeholder is working fine but I also need to populate signer Details like (Full name and date).

**What I have tried:**
For signature in Stimulsoft, I am using this tag `pdfunsignedsignaturefield`.
Tried [this documentation](https://dynamo-docs.documill.com/integrations-and-additional-modules/integration-implementation-guide/adding-docusign-placeholder-fields-into-document.html) and alias for name and date fields but no luck in that

**Question:**
Need to populate Signer details in DocuSign (report/document generated in Stimulsoft)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is still looking for the answer, there are below form fields which you can add in stimulsoft Tag (Field->Behavior-> interaction-> Tag)

https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/esign101/concepts/tabs/pdf-transform/

Answer (score 0):

You want the output from Stimulsoft to be processed by DocuSign so the resulting DocuSign envelope (transaction) will include data from Stimulsoft output?

- You could have Stimulsoft create a PDF Form. The various form fields can then be converted by DocuSign into DocuSign fields (tabs).
- **Better**, I'd recommend having Stimulsoft create an HTML page. It can include specific HTML elements that will be converted to DocuSign fields.

Using HTML: see the [documentation](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/esign101/concepts/responsive/setting-tabs/)

Here's a [live example](https://apirequestbuilder.docusign.com/?eg=HTML%20responsive%20credit%20card%20form%20with%20smart%20sections) showing how an HTML page can be converted to an envelope with tabs. The "smart sections" are added via additional Envelope:create attributes.

**Note:** if your developer account is missing access to the advanced features used for these examples, ask DocuSign support to turn those features on for your developer account.

Comment: Thank you @Larry. instead of tabs I am more interested in populating data on the document, Suppose I have 3 fields (Signature, name and Date). I want DocuSign to Populate those fields automatically on the document. Is it possible? If yes then How?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you want. Please update (edit) your question to be more clear. Do you want the DocuSign signer to input their name? Do you want the signer to input the date when the document was signed, or some arbitrary date? All inputs by DocuSign signers are done via fields (tabs)

Comment: Yes, I want Docusign to enter the signer name on the document but not uploading document manually. I want to find out placeholders(name and date) for Stimulsoft report which should be detected by Docusign automatically.